# SQL Server 2012 Backup problems

Tags: sql-server, backup

I'm working on a C# program and it has a database backup menu.
It's working well on my computer on which Visual studio is installed. But when I make a setup file and publish it to another computer, it doesn't work and it closes automatically when we click backup button.
Help me what can I do, please.

Comment: Your question is too broad..Please provide more details like your actual code, What error you are facing etc.,

Comment: We need a lot more information... like the code involved here, any errors, etc. Have you stepped through it in debug mode?

Comment: just a minute i will send my codes picture

Comment: ServerConnection srvConn = new ServerConnection(con);
                Server srvr = new Server(srvConn);

Comment: Backup backupdb = new Backup();
backupdb.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
backupdb.Database = "db";
 SaveFileDialog savefd = new SaveFileDialog();savefd.Filter = "Backup File (*.Bak)|*.Bak";
 savefd.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss");
                        savefd.ShowDialog();
                        
                            BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(savefd.FileName, DeviceType.File);
                            backupdb.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
                            backupdb.SqlBackup(srvr);

Comment: what happend what can i do

Comment: Modify the app to wrap the calls in try/catch.  When you catch errors, log them somewhere for analysis and post the errors here.

Comment: Instead of adding comments, please edit your question with these details.

Comment: Try adding a break point in your code and doing some basic debugging. Adding a try/catch may also help.